# jqGrid not initializing. Is this the right approach?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

thanks for your time helping me on my first steps with jqGrid. I have a question regarding how to approach the grids I'm needing to deploy.

The data to be shown in the Grid is coming from a DataSet. I have the tables parsed into an already validated Json string. So, the logic would be to use datatype: 'jsonstring' but I've also read that jsonstring along with datastr is kind of not up to date in terms of paging. So what's your advice?

In this first sketch, jqGrid is not being initialized. Blank page. And for narrowing the error I've replaced the <%=jsonString%> with a local variable containing the jsonstring: same result.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />    
<link href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#Grid").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            datastr: <%=jsonString%>;
            mtype: 'POST',
            height: 100,
            width: 500,
            colNames: ['Name', 'LastName', 'Qty', 'Yold', 'Address'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'Name', index: 'PCRC', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'LastName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'Qty', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'Yold', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'Address', width: 100, sortable: true }

                ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#GridPager',
            sortname: 'Name',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            caption: 'Test Grid'
        });

        $("#Grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#GridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    });
});
</script>
```

The grid is not displayed at all.

```
  <table id="Grid" ></table>
<div id="GridPager"></div>
```

Do you see something I may be missing out?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Version: jquery-1.8.2.js
Oleg: No service.

And here's the jsonstring example I used for variable data.

```
var data =  {"Tables":[{"Rows":[{"Name":"Alex","LastName":"Grey","Qty":3,"Yold":20,"Address":"27 rd"},{"Name":"Sebastian","LastName":"Wallace","Qty":78,"Yold":27,"Address":"33 xx"},{"Name":"Rose","LastName":"Garner","Qty":1,"Yold":33,"Address":"1111 rtd."},{"Name":"Carole","LastName":"Stewart","Qty":45,"Yold":18,"Address":"122 dr."}]}]};       
        $("#GridCantidadPendientes").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            datastr: data,
            //and so on
```

The data provided for the grid, as said before, is coming from DataSets. I have the DataSets parsed to jsonstring, but if in order to make the grid work I need to build JSON objets instead of string I could do that. But as far as I've tried I can't make the grid work.
Thanks again.

**UPDATE 2.**

After a few corrections the grid is now up. But it's blank. Can't get the data in wether it's from code behind or js variable.

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use? You wrote "the tables parsed into an already validated Json string", but you don't describe the exact format of input data. You should give hint to jqGrid about the exact format structure. It's good if you just include example of the data in your question. Do you have some service which could provide JSON data per HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: I assume when you replaced the `<%=jsonString%>` you were getting rid of the `;` ?

Comment: @Oleg I updated the question so you have more information about my set up. Thanks

Comment: @Mark Yes, seems like it doesn't like it, string or variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your update, `data` is not a JSON string, it's just a variable.  You may want to use `datatype: local` instead.

The data is also not formatted in the way that jqGrid expects.  You'll need to either fix the format or write a custom `jsonReader` (or `localReader`) function.  Check the [docs on retrieving data](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) for details.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I've pasted the content of 'data' into a jsonstring validator y it claims to be a json string. Using that variable as datastr isn't enough for jqgrid?

Comment: It's a variable, not a string, so when the Reader tries to JSON.parse() it, nothing good is going to happen.  You could convert it to JSON by wrapping it in quotes, but that won't help the other issue of it not having the layout that jqGrid expects.